# Python PyQt5 threading don't work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

i want to create a progress bar showing(as busy) until the code of a button ends .My target is to show it when button(connected to function) pressed  ,stay visible as code runs , and hide  it when the function connected to the button ends.This task is done partially but my progress bar setVisible(True) waits until code ends and they show.
My code is here:

```
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QWidget,QApplication, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class ProgressThread(QtCore.QThread):
    job_done = QtCore.pyqtSignal('QString')
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gui_bar = None
    def do_work(self):
        self.job_done.emit(self.gui_bar)

    def run(self):
        self.do_work()

class mainProgram(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                   #main window
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainProgram, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.progress_thread = ProgressThread()
        self.progress_thread.job_done.connect(self.on_job_start)
        self.create_ui()

        self.B_aerodrome_data.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)

        self.B_aerodrome_data.clicked.connect(self.aerodrome_data)


    def aerodrome_data(self):          #def i want with start show progress bar
        #here show progressBar(self.progress.setVisible(True) and update gui)
        #do many staffs of code here that takes time

        #here hide progress bar and update gui 

    def start_thread(self):
        self.progress_thread.gui_bar = self.progress.setVisible(False)
        self.progress_thread.start()

    def on_job_done(self):
        print("Generated string : ")
        self.progress.setVisible(False)


    def on_job_start(self):
        print("aaaaaaaaaa")
        self.progress.setRange(0,0)
        self.progress.setVisible(True)
    def create_ui(self):
        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setVisible(False)
        self.progress.setGeometry(200, 205, 250, 20)
        self.progress.setRange(0, 0)
        self.progress.setObjectName("progress")
        #self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        #layout.addWidget(self.button)

if __name__ == "__main__":                       
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    nextGui = mainProgram()
    nextGui.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The Ui_Mainwindow is here:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1371, 924)
        MainWindow.setAcceptDrops(True)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/356.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.L_adinput = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.L_adinput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 141, 31))
        self.L_adinput.setObjectName("L_adinput")
        # self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        # self.progress.setGeometry(200, 205, 250, 20)
        # self.progress.setProperty("value", 0)
        # self.progress.setObjectName("progress")
        self.L_progress = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.L_progress.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 141, 31))
        self.L_progress.setObjectName("L_progress")
        self.B_aerodrome_data = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_aerodrome_data.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 100, 271, 41))
        self.B_aerodrome_data.setObjectName("B_aerodrome_data")
        self.T_aerodrome_ouput = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.T_aerodrome_ouput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 561, 371))
        self.T_aerodrome_ouput.setReadOnly(True)
        self.T_aerodrome_ouput.setObjectName("T_aerodrome_ouput")
        self.B_alternates = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_alternates.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 160, 271, 41))
        self.B_alternates.setObjectName("B_alternates")
        self.B_weather = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_weather.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 220, 271, 41))
        self.B_weather.setObjectName("B_weather")
        self.B_fuel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_fuel.setEnabled(True)
        self.B_fuel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1050, 100, 271, 41))
        self.B_fuel.setObjectName("B_fuel")
        self.set_path1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.set_path1.setEnabled(True)
        self.set_path1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 160, 101, 31))
        self.set_path1.setObjectName("set_path1")
        self.set_path2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.set_path2.setEnabled(True)
        self.set_path2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 210, 101, 31))
        self.set_path2.setObjectName("set_path2")
        self.set_path3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.set_path3.setEnabled(True)
        self.set_path3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 260, 101, 31))
        self.set_path3.setObjectName("set_path3")
        self.set_path4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.set_path4.setEnabled(True)
        self.set_path4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 310, 101, 31))
        self.set_path4.setObjectName("set_path4")
        self.set_path5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.set_path5.setEnabled(True)
        self.set_path5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1100, 360, 101, 31))
        self.set_path5.setObjectName("set_path5")
        self.tool1 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1240, 170, 25, 19))
        self.tool1.setObjectName("tool1")
        self.tool2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1240, 220, 25, 20))
        self.tool2.setObjectName("tool2")
        self.tool3 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1240, 270, 25, 19))
        self.tool3.setObjectName("tool3")
        self.tool4 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1240, 320, 25, 19))
        self.tool4.setObjectName("tool4")
        self.tool1x = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool1x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1280, 220, 25, 19))
        self.tool1x.setObjectName("tool1x")
        self.tool2x = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool2x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1280, 270, 25, 19))
        self.tool2x.setObjectName("tool2x")
        self.tool3x = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool3x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1280, 320, 25, 19))
        self.tool3x.setObjectName("tool3x")
        self.tool4x = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.tool4x.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1280, 370, 25, 19))
        self.tool4x.setObjectName("tool4x")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralWidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(990, -50, 20, 851))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.T_aerodromes_input = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.T_aerodromes_input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 100, 331, 71))
        self.T_aerodromes_input.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.T_aerodromes_input.setObjectName("T_aerodromes_input")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 200, 161, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.B_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 230, 41, 31))
        self.B_print.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/printer.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.B_print.setIcon(icon1)
        self.B_print.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(41, 31))
        self.B_print.setObjectName("B_print")
        self.B_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.B_clear.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 230, 41, 31))
        self.B_clear.setText("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 30, 271, 41))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 75 11pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1050, 30, 271, 41))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 75 11pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/clear.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.B_clear.setIcon(icon2)
        self.B_clear.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(41, 31))
        self.B_clear.setObjectName("B_clear")
        self.L_adinput.raise_()
        self.L_progress.raise_()
        self.B_aerodrome_data.raise_()
        self.T_aerodrome_ouput.raise_()
        self.B_alternates.raise_()
        self.B_weather.raise_()
        self.B_fuel.raise_()
        self.set_path2.raise_()
        self.set_path3.raise_()
        self.set_path4.raise_()
        self.set_path5.raise_()
        self.tool1.raise_()
        self.set_path1.raise_()
        self.tool2.raise_()
        self.tool3.raise_()
        self.tool4.raise_()
        self.tool1x.raise_()
        self.tool2x.raise_()
        self.tool3x.raise_()
        self.tool4x.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.T_aerodromes_input.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.B_print.raise_()
        self.B_clear.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tool1.clicked.connect(self.tool2.show)
        self.tool1.clicked.connect(self.set_path2.show)
        self.tool2.clicked.connect(self.tool3.show)
        self.tool3.clicked.connect(self.tool4.show)
        self.tool3.clicked.connect(self.set_path4.show)
        self.tool4.clicked.connect(self.set_path5.show)
        self.tool2.clicked.connect(self.set_path3.show)
        self.tool4x.clicked.connect(self.set_path5.hide)
        self.tool3x.clicked.connect(self.tool4.hide)
        self.tool3x.clicked.connect(self.set_path4.hide)
        self.tool2x.clicked.connect(self.tool3.hide)
        self.tool2x.clicked.connect(self.set_path3.hide)
        self.tool1x.clicked.connect(self.tool2.hide)
        self.tool1x.clicked.connect(self.set_path2.hide)
        self.tool4x.clicked.connect(self.tool4x.hide)
        self.tool3x.clicked.connect(self.tool3x.hide)
        self.tool2x.clicked.connect(self.tool2x.hide)
        self.tool1x.clicked.connect(self.tool1x.hide)
        self.tool1.clicked.connect(self.tool1x.show)
        self.tool2.clicked.connect(self.tool2x.show)
        self.tool3.clicked.connect(self.tool3x.show)
        self.tool4.clicked.connect(self.tool4x.show)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Planner"))
        self.L_adinput.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ICAO LOCATORS"))
        self.L_progress.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Progress"))
        self.B_aerodrome_data.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "AERODROME DATA"))
        # self.T_aerodrome_ouput.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
# "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
# "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
# "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
# "<p style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.B_alternates.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ALTERNATES XLSX"))
        self.B_weather.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "WEATHER BRIEFING"))
        self.B_fuel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FUEL XLSX"))
        self.set_path1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SET FORM"))
        self.set_path2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SET FORM"))
        self.set_path3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SET FORM"))
        self.set_path4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SET FORM"))
        self.set_path5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SET FORM"))
        self.tool1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.tool2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.tool3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.tool4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.tool1x.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.tool2x.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.tool3x.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.tool4x.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "X"))
        self.T_aerodromes_input.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set 4 character ICAO Locator here , divided by spaces..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OUTPUT"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GENERAL"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FUEL"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You could improve the format your code, in addition to place consistent code since I am trying to reproduce your code and has many inconsistencies.

Comment: Sorry for this i have a huge code and i tried to parse the code needed.I editing now..

Comment: It's okay to put a minimum code but this must be verifiable, I think you should know that you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think that job_done is the signal that should be issued when the task ends. Am I right? If so, why do you connect it to on_job_start?

Comment: self.progress(the progress bar) is hidden when programs starts.I want when B_aerodrome_data pressed and connect to the function(aerodrome_data) show progress bar and keep it untill function ends(setVisible(False))

Comment: I suppose the statement `self.B_aerodrome_data.clicked.connect(self.start_thread)` is a test.

Comment: Nope i thought maybe if i call this first maybe did the trick xd....

Comment: Why should the job_done signal return a QString? : `job_done = QtCore.pyqtSignal('QString')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162232/discussion-between---and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I see that you have created functions unnecessarily, I have eliminated some. According to what you tell me, it is not necessary for the signal to carry information, so I will create a signal without parameters. the slot connected to the button must make visible the `QProgressBar` and start the thread, and the signal job_done must connect with the method that hides the `QProgressBar`, in the following example use `QThread::sleep()` to emulate some processing.

```
class ProgressThread(QtCore.QThread):
    job_done = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def do_work(self):
        QtCore.QThread.sleep(2) # emulate processing
        self.job_done.emit()

    def run(self):
        self.do_work()


class mainProgram(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):  # main window
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainProgram, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.progress_thread = ProgressThread()
        self.progress_thread.job_done.connect(self.on_job_done)
        self.create_ui()
        self.B_aerodrome_data.clicked.connect(self.aerodrome_data)

    def aerodrome_data(self):
        self.start_thread()

    def start_thread(self):
        self.progress.setVisible(True)
        self.progress_thread.start()

    def on_job_done(self):
        print("Generated string : ")
        self.progress.setVisible(False)

    def create_ui(self):
        [...]
```

Comment: Thx i can see it now . I will try alone to emit stop signal

Answer (score 0):

try this code, you will find your solution from here.
when you will press the button thread will start and emit int data to the progress bar from 0-100

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget,QApplication,QVBoxLayout,QPushButton,QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QThread,pyqtSignal
import time
import sys

class THREAD(QThread): # QThread is use for parallal execution

    EMIT=pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        count=0

        while count<=100:
            count+=1
            self.EMIT.emit(count)
            time.sleep(0.1)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ICON="icon.jpg"
        self.TITLE="ROBO Science LAB"
        self.TOP = 100
        self.LEFT = 100
        self.WIDTH = 700
        self.HEIGHT = 500

        self.InitWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(ComponentManagement())
        self.show()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(self.ICON))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.TITLE)
        self.setGeometry(self.TOP,self.LEFT,self.WIDTH,self.HEIGHT)

class ComponentManagement(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.UIcomponent()


    def UIcomponent(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.progress1 = QProgressBar()

        BUTTON = QPushButton("Click to start progress")
        BUTTON.setStyleSheet("background:#E67E22")
        BUTTON.clicked.connect(self.StartProgressBar)

        vbox.addWidget(self.progress1)
        vbox.addWidget(BUTTON)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def SetProgressValue(self, val):
        self.progress1.setValue(val)

    def StartProgressBar(self):
        self.ThredObject = THREAD()
        self.ThredObject.EMIT.connect(self.SetProgressValue)
        self.ThredObject.start()


if __name__=="__main__":
    App=QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Please also try to explain your solution with some comments